# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///path/to/source.js.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, source-maps, chrome-devtools-protocol

When I run a **Node.js typescript** project with **--inspect** then I go to URL "localhost:9229/json/list" and select URL "devtoolsFrontendUrlCompat" (***NOTE: need to remove "chrome-" from thr start of URL as GOOGLE chrome team again MESSED UP the URL else it will go in google search***).

When the dev tools start on URL "devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/d34a4b4c-8583-43b7-90e3-bec3f1809995" then I only see compiled javascript files on the dev tools but source maps are not loaded as per below screen shot:

[DevTools failed to load SourceMap][1]

*Before few months everything (including source maps loading) was working but now when I am trying to do the same then all I can see is the compiled javascript file but I can't debug typescript files as CHROME FAILS TO LOAD THESE SOURCE MAPS. I searched everywhere online and surprised that no one else asked this and really HATE GOOGLE chrome team for messing chrome with EVERY SINGLE RELEASE. Seriously they are the worst*.

Would be great if any Node.js developers can help me here who know the solution. Please.

Comment: @Kody - I'm seeing the same thing. In node 14 they at least update the url to handle the new 'devtools' protocol. But i am also seeing the same sourcemap issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528094/why-doesnt-a-url-with-chrome-devtools-open-the-devtools