# Why doesn't a url with chrome-devtools:// open the devtools?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I have a nodejs server running with --inspect

When i look at the meta information at (docker port)   http://10.0.3.6:4080/json/list i get the following:

```
// 20200821141205
// http://10.0.3.6:4080/json/list

[
  {
    "description": "node.js instance",
    "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=10.0.3.6:4080/15d3e459-3f00-442f-b442-a35cea47d811",
    "devtoolsFrontendUrlCompat": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=10.0.3.6:4080/15d3e459-3f00-442f-b442-a35cea47d811",
    "faviconUrl": "https://nodejs.org/static/images/favicons/favicon.ico",
    "id": "15d3e459-3f00-442f-b442-a35cea47d811",
    "title": "src/server.ts",
    "type": "node",
    "url": "file:///app/src/server.ts",
    "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://10.0.3.6:4080/15d3e459-3f00-442f-b442-a35cea47d811"
  }
]
```

I would expect that opening the `devToolsFrontendUrl` would open the chrome devtools page. It instead tries to execute a google query:

```
Your search - chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=10.0 ... - did not match any documents.
```

How do i make chrome load the devtoolsFrontendUrl in the Devtools Node Inspector?

Comment: It's changed to `devtools://` in new Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm - that seemed to fix the protocol issue - it's still saying ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both chrome and the node projects updated their protocol name from `chrome-devtools` to `devtools`

Updating from node 10 to node 14 gave me the following results...

```
// 20200821150718
// http://10.0.3.6:4080/json

[
  {
    "description": "node.js instance",
    "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=10.0.3.6:4080/50b21fd5-04d4-407a-8e1e-cb1937e0419b",
    "devtoolsFrontendUrlCompat": "devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=10.0.3.6:4080/50b21fd5-04d4-407a-8e1e-cb1937e0419b",
    "faviconUrl": "https://nodejs.org/static/images/favicons/favicon.ico",
    "id": "50b21fd5-04d4-407a-8e1e-cb1937e0419b",
    "title": "src/server.ts",
    "type": "node",
    "url": "file:///app/src/server.ts",
    "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://10.0.3.6:4080/50b21fd5-04d4-407a-8e1e-cb1937e0419b"
  }
]
```